# Azure Data Factory HTTP Connector Data Copy - Bank Of England Statistical Database

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use the HTTP connector to read a CSV of data from the BoE statistical database.
Take the SONIA rate for instance.
There is a download button for a CSV extract.

I've converted this to the following URL which downloads a CSV via web browser.

[https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/_iadb-fromshowcolumns.asp?csv.x=yes&Datefrom=01/Dec/2021&Dateto=01/Dec/2021 &SeriesCodes=IUDSOIA&CSVF=TN&UsingCodes=Y][1]

Putting this in the Base URL it connects and pulls the data.
I'm trying to split this out so that I can parameterise some of it.

Base

https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database

Relative

_iadb-fromshowcolumns.asp?csv.x=yes&Datefrom=01/Dec/2021&Dateto=01/Dec/2021 &SeriesCodes=IUDSOIA&CSVF=TN&UsingCodes=Y

It won't fetch the data, however when it's all combined in the base URL it does.
I've tried to add a "/" at the start of the relative URL as well and that hasn't worked either.

According to the documentation ADF puts the "/" in for you "[Base]/[Relative]"

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Dan

[1]: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/_iadb-fromshowcolumns.asp?csv.x=yes&Datefrom=01/Dec/2021&Dateto=01/Dec/2021 &SeriesCodes=IUDSOIA&CSVF=TN&UsingCodes=Y

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way you could download that data directly as a `csv` file. The data seems to be manually copied from the site, using their `Save as` option.

[image]

They have used read-only block and hidden elements, I doubt there would any easy way or out of the box method within ADF web activity to help on this.

You can just manually copy-paste into a `csv` file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
I've been trying different things and managed to get it working using the following URL.
https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/_iadb-fromshowcolumns.asp?csv.x=yes&Datefrom=01/Dec/2021&Dateto=01/Dec/2021 &SeriesCodes=IUDSOIA&CSVF=TN&UsingCodes=Y

If I split this into a Base and Relative URL (as I'll be looking to parameterise the dates).
It fails.

Comment: Base
https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database
Relative
_iadb-fromshowcolumns.asp?csv.x=yes&Datefrom=01/Dec/2021&Dateto=01/Dec/2021 &SeriesCodes=IUDSOIA&CSVF=TN&UsingCodes=Y

It won't fetch the data, however when it's all combined in the base URL it does.
I've tried to add a "/" at the start of the relative URL as well and that hasn't worked either.